# Generar .xlt desde pandas

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

Tengo un codigo que combina dos plantillas de excel en una sola hoja usando pandas y necesito exportarla en formato .XLT, este es un formato antiguo de excel llamado "Plantilla de excel" que comprende desde el 97 al 2003. Buscando en los motores de escritura para python no me he topado con esta extensión.

¿Es posible generar de alguna manera el archivo con dicha extension?

este es mi codigo hasta el momento para intentar exportar, he probado con el motor de pandas y openpyxl.

```
result = pd.merge(df1,df2,
    on=["CODIGOS"],
    how='left'
    )
result = result.loc[:, ['CODIGOS']]
result.to_excel('procesado.xlt',index=False, engine='openpyxel')
```

Comment: Creo que necesitarás otra librería diferente a pandas, en Google sale https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/

Comment: sabes si esta librería añade .xlt? o es solamente .xls?

Comment: no la he manejado nunca. Hay más librerías que parece ser que sí trabajan con xlt pero nunca las he usado. Por eso no lo pongo como respuesta, porque hay que seguir investigando